# How to display graphql value in component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

### Why I am getting `Missing price attribute on result` error?

I am following [the official guide](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#query-with-parameters)

Please help me to get **price** value into my vue component?

*price.vue component*

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ price }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      price: ""
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    price: gql`
      query price {
        dish(id: 1) {
          price
        }
      }
    `
  }
};
</script>
```

---

*Console log*

[image: console]

---

*Actual data as seen on GraphQL client*

[image: data]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was trying to reach to a value inside dish Object. I have just renamed **price** to **dish**.

I hope this will help someone.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ dish.price }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dish: ""
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    dish: gql`
      query dish {
        # dish is returned data
        dish(id: 1) {
          price
        }
      }
    `
  }
};
</script>
```

Simplest working form of same code is...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ dish.price }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";
export default {
  apollo: {
    dish: gql`
      {
        dish(id: 1) {
          price
        }
      }
    `
  }
};
</script>
```

#### Check out the solution clone from github [sample app](https://github.com/kaanguru/apollo-jwt)